# Using Pandas to pd.read_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I have a large spreadsheet file (.xlsx) that I'm processing using python pandas. It happens that I need data from two tabs (sheets) in that large file. One of the tabs has a ton of data and the other is just a few square cells.

When I use [`pd.read_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html) on *any* worksheet, it looks to me like the whole file is loaded (not just the worksheet I'm interested in). So when I use the method twice (once for each sheet), I effectively have to suffer the whole workbook being read in twice (even though we're only using the specified sheet).

How do I only load specific sheet(s) with `pd.read_excel()`?

Comment: I give an example in this other post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66280555/778261

Answer (score 609, accepted):

Try [`pd.ExcelFile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#excelfile-class):

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
```

As noted by @HaPsantran, the entire Excel file is read in during the `ExcelFile()` call (there doesn't appear to be a way around this). This merely saves you from having to read the same file in each time you want to access a new sheet.

Note that the `sheet_name` argument to `pd.read_excel()` can be the name of the sheet (as above), an integer specifying the sheet number (eg 0, 1, etc), a list of sheet names or indices, or `None`. If a list is provided, it returns a dictionary where the keys are the sheet names/indices and the values are the data frames. The default is to simply return the first sheet (ie, `sheet_name=0`).

If `None` is specified, **all** sheets are returned, as a `{sheet_name:dataframe}` dictionary.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like (last time I tested it) the first line loads in *everything*, so there's no way to efficiently pull in just a single sheet, but at least getting multiple sheets does not require multiple loads of the whole sheet.

Comment: This answer has been deprecated by pandas and now crashes for me in v0.21.0.  It should be replaced by the one given by @Mat0kan.

Comment: @DStauffman This still works fine for me and I see no indication from the code or the docs that this is deprecated. If you're having trouble with it, I'd submit an issue on the github for pandas or xlrd (the python excel parsing library used by pandas)

Comment: @Noah, thanks I looked into this some more and you're right, it does still work as long as I use `sheet_name` and not `sheetname`.  I didn't realize that was the deprecated part, because it was still working on the read_excel method, but not on the parse method.

Comment: @Noah Indeed a nice answer. Is there a way to find the active cell in the excel sheet that you read?

Comment: @Eswar I'm not sure how to do this. Maybe create a new question?

Comment: This provides massive time savings if you are reading multiple sheets from one workbook. Shaved hours off of my script. Thank you!

Comment: @Noah How to read multiple worksheets of the same workbook in a .CSV file using pandas ?

Comment: After importing the excel file you can get a list of sheets inside with `xls.sheet_names`

Comment: Just a heads up.. `pd.ExcelFile` uses  xlrd, but as of Dec 2020 xlrd no longer supports xls or xlsx files. You can get around this with `xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls' engine='openpyxl')`

Comment: @EmeEme fyi newer versions of pandas default to using openpyxl

Answer (score 273):

There are a few options:

**Read all sheets directly into an ordered dictionary.**

```
import pandas as pd

# for pandas version >= 0.21.0
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)

# for pandas version < 0.21.0
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=None)
```

**Read the first sheet directly into dataframe**

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel_file_path.xls')
# this will read the first sheet into df
```

**Read the excel file and get a list of sheets. Then choose and load the sheets.**

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('excel_file_path.xls')

# Now you can list all sheets in the file
xls.sheet_names
# ['house', 'house_extra', ...]

# to read just one sheet to dataframe:
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name="house")
```

**Read all sheets and store it in a dictionary. Same as first but more explicit.**

```
# to read all sheets to a map
sheet_to_df_map = {}
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    sheet_to_df_map[sheet_name] = xls.parse(sheet_name)
    # you can also use sheet_index [0,1,2..] instead of sheet name.
```

Thanks @ihightower for pointing it out way to read all sheets and @toto_tico,@red-headphone for pointing out the version issue.

> sheetname : string, int, mixed list of strings/ints, or None, default 0
> Deprecated since version 0.21.0: Use sheet_name instead [Source Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: in latest pandas that i have(0.20.3), to read all sheets to a map.. all that is required is `df_sheet_map = pd.read_excel(file_fullpath, sheetname=None)`, this will have the sheets in a dictionary automatically.. and access the sheet as dataframe like this: `df_sheet_map['house']`

Comment: @ihightower This is a dictionary though, not a map. I'm answering now because I was struggling with this function, since in a recent version of pandas they dropped the support for kwargs in read_excel and I'm trying to get around it

Comment: Minor correction to @ihightower's comment, the parameter `sheetname` should be `sheet_name`, otherwise this is a good answer... the sheets and associated df are imported as a `dict`.

Answer (score 49):

You could also specify the sheet name as a parameter:

```
data_file = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheet_name="sheet_name")
```

will upload only the sheet `"sheet_name"`.

Answer (score 47):

You can also use the index for the sheet:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
sheet1 = xls.parse(0)
```

will give the first worksheet. for the second worksheet:

```
sheet2 = xls.parse(1)
```

Comment: In case you want a list of the sheet names, than just type
xls.sheet_names

Answer (score 33):

There are various options depending on the use case:

1. If one doesn't know the sheets names.
2. If the sheets name is not relevant.
3. If one knows the name of the sheets.

Below we will look closely at each of the options.

See the Notes section for information such as finding out the sheet names.

---

**Option 1**

If one doesn't know the sheets names

```
# Read all sheets in your File
df = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
    
# Prints all the sheets name in an ordered dictionary
print(df.keys())
```

Then, depending on the sheet one wants to read, one can pass each of them to a specific `dataframe`, such as

```
sheet1_df = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=SHEET1NAME)
sheet2_df = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=SHEET2NAME)
```

---

**Option 2**

If the name is not relevant and all one cares about is the position of the sheet. Let's say one wants only the first sheet

```
# Read all sheets in your File
df = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

sheet1 = list(df.keys())[0]
```

Then, depending on the sheet name, one can pass each it to a specific `dataframe`, such as

```
sheet1_df = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=SHEET1NAME)
```

---

**Option 3**

Here we will consider the case where one knows the name of the sheets.
For the examples, one will consider that there are three sheets named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, and `Sheet3`. The content in each is the same, and looks like this

```
     0         1     2
0   85   January  2000
1   95  February  2001
2  105     March  2002
3  115     April  2003
4  125       May  2004
5  135      June  2005
```

With this, depending on one's goals, there are multiple approaches:

- Store everything in same dataframe. One approach would be to concat the sheets as follows

  ```
  sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
  df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet) for sheet in sheets], ignore_index = True)

  [Out]:

        0         1     2
  0    85   January  2000
  1    95  February  2001
  2   105     March  2002
  3   115     April  2003
  4   125       May  2004
  5   135      June  2005
  6    85   January  2000
  7    95  February  2001
  8   105     March  2002
  9   115     April  2003
  10  125       May  2004
  11  135      June  2005
  12   85   January  2000
  13   95  February  2001
  14  105     March  2002
  15  115     April  2003
  16  125       May  2004
  17  135      June  2005
  ```

  Basically, this how [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) works ([Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)):

  [image]
- Store each sheet in a different dataframe (let's say, `df1`, `df2`, ...)

  ```
  sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']

  for i, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
      globals()['df' + str(i + 1)] = pd.read_excel('FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name = sheet)

  [Out]:

  # df1
       0         1     2
  0   85   January  2000
  1   95  February  2001
  2  105     March  2002
  3  115     April  2003
  4  125       May  2004
  5  135      June  2005

  # df2
       0         1     2
  0   85   January  2000
  1   95  February  2001
  2  105     March  2002
  3  115     April  2003
  4  125       May  2004
  5  135      June  2005

  # df3
       0         1     2
  0   85   January  2000
  1   95  February  2001
  2  105     March  2002
  3  115     April  2003
  4  125       May  2004
  5  135      June  2005
  ```

---

**Notes:**

- If one wants to know the sheets names, one can use the [`ExcelFile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/io.html#excelfile-class) class as follows

  ```
  sheets = pd.ExcelFile('FILENAME.xlsx').sheet_names

  [Out]: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
  ```
- In this case one is assuming that the file `FILENAME.xlsx` is on the same directory as the script one is running.

  - If the file is in a folder of the current directory called Data, one way would be to use `r'./Data/FILENAME.xlsx'` create a variable, such as `path` as follows

    ```
     path = r'./Data/Test.xlsx'

     df = pd.read_excel(r'./Data/FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
    ```
- [This](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/user_guide/io.html#reading-excel-files) might be a relevant read.

Answer (score 15):

```
pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

by default read the first sheet of workbook.

```
pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheetname')
```

read the specific sheet of workbook and

```
pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name = None)
```

read all the worksheets from excel to pandas dataframe as a type of OrderedDict means nested dataframes, all the worksheets as dataframes collected inside dataframe and it's type is OrderedDict.

Answer (score 15):

If you are interested in reading all sheets and merging them together. The best and fastest way to do it

```
sheet_to_df_map = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheet_name=None)
mdf = pd.concat(sheet_to_df_map, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

This will convert all the sheet into a single data frame m_df

Comment: In this case, how would you slice sheet-specific data?

Since we don't have any column for sheet name.

Answer (score 5):

If:

- you want multiple, but not all, worksheets, and
- you want a single df as an output

Then, you can pass a list of worksheet names. Which you could populate manually:

```
import pandas as pd
    
path = "C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Data\\"
file = "data.xlsx"
sheet_lst_wanted = ["01_SomeName","05_SomeName","12_SomeName"] # tab names from Excel

### import and compile data ###
    
# read all sheets from list into an ordered dictionary    
dict_temp = pd.read_excel(path+file, sheet_name= sheet_lst_wanted)

# concatenate the ordered dict items into a dataframe
df = pd.concat(dict_temp, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

OR

A bit of automation is possible if your desired worksheets have a common naming convention that also allows you to differentiate from unwanted sheets:

```
# substitute following block for the sheet_lst_wanted line in above block

import xlrd

# string common to only worksheets you want
str_like = "SomeName" 
    
### create list of sheet names in Excel file ###
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(path+file, on_demand=True)
sheet_lst = xls.sheet_names()
    
### create list of sheets meeting criteria  ###
sheet_lst_wanted = []
    
for s in sheet_lst:
    # note: following conditional statement based on my sheets ending with the string defined in sheet_like
    if s[-len(str_like):] == str_like:
        sheet_lst_wanted.append(s)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer! You can also use tuple unpacking if you have just a couple sheets to read. `df1, df2 = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=["sheet1", "sheet2"]).values()`

Answer (score 5):

You can read all the sheets using the following lines

```
import pandas as pd
file_instance = pd.ExcelFile('your_file.xlsx')

main_df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', sheet_name=name) for name in file_instance.sheet_names] , axis=0)
```

Comment: You might want to add .reset_index(drop=True)  at the end in case you don't want different index numbers for each sheet.

Answer (score 4):

```
df = pd.read_excel('FileName.xlsx', 'SheetName')
```

This will read sheet `SheetName` from file `FileName.xlsx`

Answer (score 2):

Yes unfortunately it will always load the full file. If you're doing this repeatedly probably best to extract the sheets to separate CSVs and then load separately. You can automate that process with [d6tstack](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/) which also adds additional features like checking if all the columns are equal across all sheets or multiple Excel files.

```
import d6tstack
c = d6tstack.convert_xls.XLStoCSVMultiSheet('multisheet.xlsx')
c.convert_all() # ['multisheet-Sheet1.csv','multisheet-Sheet2.csv']
```

See [d6tstack Excel examples](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-excel.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

If you have saved the excel file in the same folder as your python program (relative paths) then you just need to mention sheet number along with file name.

Example:

```
 data = pd.read_excel("wt_vs_ht.xlsx", "Sheet2")
 print(data)
 x = data.Height
 y = data.Weight
 plt.plot(x,y,'x')
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

df will be a list containing each sheet as dataframe in each index.

```
import pandas as pd

your_file = 'your_file.xlsx'
sh = pd.read_excel(your_file, sheet_name=None)

name = list(sh.keys())
df = []

for i in range(len(name)):
  df.append(pd.read_excel(your_file, name[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read single sheet from Excel file using `read_excel`

```
df = pd.read_excel(config_file, sheet_name = 'euro-currency-rates')
```

Read Multiple Sheets from Excel File

```
excel_df    = pd.read_excel(self.excel_file, sheet_name=[0, 1, 2])          # Read 1st, 2nd, 3rd Sheets, Returns a Dictionary with each key number 0,1,2 and each corresponding values sheet data frame
# excel_df  = pd.read_excel(self.excel_file, sheet_name=['sheetA', 'sheetB', 'sheetC'])
# excel_df  = pd.read_excel(self.excel_file, sheet_name=None)       # Read All sheets
sheet1_df   = excel_df[0]
sheet2_df   = excel_df[1]
sheet3_df   = excel_df[2]
```