# How to open an excel file with multiple sheets in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, import

I have an excel file composed of several sheets. I need to load them as separate dataframes individually. What would be a similar function as pd.read_csv("") for this kind of task?

P.S. due to the size I cannot copy and paste individual sheets in excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use pandas `read_excel()` method that accepts a `sheet_name` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name="sheet_name")
```

Multiple data frames can be loaded by passing in a list. For a more in-depth explanation of how `read_excel()` works see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: `sheetname=` has been replaced with `sheet_name=`

Answer (score 7):

If you can't type out each sheet name and want to read whole worksheet try this:

```
                dfname=pd.ExcelFile('C://full_path.xlsx')
                print(dfname.sheet_names)
                df=pd.read_excel('C://fullpath.xlsx')
                for items in dfname.sheet_names[1:]:
                    dfnew=pd.read_excel(full_path,sheet_name=items)
                    df=pd.concat([df,dfnew])
```

The thing is that pd.read_excel() can read the very first sheet and rest are unread.So you can use this

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
# setting sheet_name = None, reads all sheets into a dict
sheets = pandas.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=None)  
# i will be the keys in a dictionary object
# the values are the dataframes of each sheet
for i in sheets: 
    print(f"sheet[{i}]")
    print(f"sheet[{i}].columns={sheets[i].columns}")
    for index, row in sheets[i].iterrows():
        print(f"index={index} row={row}")
```

Answer (score 0):

exFile = ExcelFile(f) #load file f

data = ExcelFile.parse(exFile) #this creates a dataframe out of the first sheet in file