# Separate data from one column into three columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in an excel which contains a mix of First Names, Last Names and Job titles. Only pattern that can be observed is - in each set of 3 rows, every 1st row is first name, 2nd row is last name and 3rd row is job title. I want to create 3 different columns and and segregate this data 
Sample data:

```
John
Bush
Manager
Katrina
Cohn
Secretary
```

I want: John , Bush , Manager as one row going in three different columns under First Name, Last name and Job title respectively. Like -

```
First Name   Last Name    Job Title
John         Bush         Manager
Katrina      Cohn         Secretary
```

How can we achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series([
        'John',
        'Bush',
        'Manager',
        'Katrina',
        'Cohn',
        'Secretary'])

df = pd.DataFrame(s.values.reshape(-1, 3),
                  columns=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Job Title'])

df
```

[image]

---

If your length of your data isn't a multiple of 3 then you can force it like this:

```
s = pd.Series([
        'John',
        'Bush',
        'Manager',
        'Katrina',
        'Cohn',
        'Secretary',
        'Bogus'])

s_ = s.iloc[:s.shape[0] // 3 * 3]
df = pd.DataFrame(s_.values.reshape(-1, 3), columns=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Job Title'])

df
```

[image]

Comment: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: @user6461192 that means your series isn't of a length that is a multiple of 3.  See edited post.

Comment: Thanks that worked. What can we do if we need to take an excel as an input, instead go hard coding the data in Series

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) to get every third element with different starting points.

```
l = ['John', 'Bush', 'Manager', 'Katrina', 'Cohn', 'Secretary']

pd.DataFrame({'First Name': l[::3], 'Last Name': l[1::3], 'Job Title': l[2::3]})
```

outputs

```
  First Name  Job Title Last Name
0       John    Manager      Bush
1    Katrina  Secretary      Cohn
```

Comment: ValueError: arrays must all be same length