# Load xlsx file from drive in colaboratory

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pydrive, google-colaboratory

How can I import MS-excel(.xlsx) file from google drive into colaboratory?

```
excel_file = drive.CreateFile({'id':'some id'})
```

does work(`drive` is a `pydrive.drive.GoogleDrive` object). But,

```
print excel_file.FetchContent()
```

returns None. And

```
excel_file.content()
```

throws:

> TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 excel_file.content()
>
> TypeError: '_io.BytesIO' object is not callable

My intent is (given some valid file 'id') to import it as an io object, which could be read by pandas `read_excel()`, and finally get a pandas dataframe out of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use `excel_file.GetContentFile` to save the file locally. Then, you can use the Pandas `read_excel` method after you `!pip install -q xlrd`.

Here's a full example:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1SU176zTQvhflodEzuiacNrzxFQ6fWeWC

What I did in more detail:

I created a new [spreadsheet in sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wmydVi1b98dzPNr7ZtbHLi3n_wEBM3W8U8ddH4I_LhI/edit?usp=sharing) to be exported as an .xlsx file.

Next, I exported it as an .xlsx file and uploaded again to Drive. The URL is:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sv4ib5i7CKWhAHZkKg-uitIkS3xwxtXM

Note the file ID. In my case it's `1Sv4ib5i7CKWhAHZkKg-uitIkS3xwxtXM`.

Then, in Colab, I tweaked the [Drive download snippet](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=/v2/external/notebooks/io.ipynb&scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk) to download the file. The key bits are:

```
file_id = '1Sv4ib5i7CKWhAHZkKg-uitIkS3xwxtXM'
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
downloaded.GetContentFile('exported.xlsx')
```

Finally, to create a Pandas DataFrame:

```
!pip install -q xlrd
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('exported.xlsx')
df
```

The `!pip install...` line installs the xlrd library, which is needed to read Excel files.

Comment: Since you're already uploading to Google Drive and converting to a Sheet then you could skip the step of uploading it again and access it from Colab simply as a Sheet as seen in this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397059/1762493

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps a simpler method:

```py
#To read/write data from Google Drive:
#Reference: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveAå
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/folder_name/file_name.xlsx')

# #When done, 
# drive.flush_and_unmount()
# print('All changes made in this colab session should now be visible in Drive.')
```

Answer (score 6):

First, I import **io**, **pandas** and **files** from *google.colab*

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
```

Then I upload the file using an upload widget

```
uploaded = files.upload()
```

You will something similar to this (click on Choose Files and upload the xlsx file):
[image]

Let's suppose that the name of the files is my_spreadsheet.xlsx, so you need to use it in the following line:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded.get('my_spreadsheet.xlsx')))
```

And that's all, now you have the first sheet in the **df** dataframe. However, if you have multiple sheets you can change the code into this:

First, move the io call to another variable

```
xlsx_file = io.BytesIO(uploaded.get('my_spreadsheet.xlsx'))
```

And then, use the new variable to specify the sheet name, like this:

```
df_first_sheet = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'My First Sheet')
df_second_sheet = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'My Second Sheet')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd

xlsx_link = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Sv4ib5i7CKWhAHZkKg-uitIkS3xwxtXM/export'
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_link)
```

if the xlsx is hosted on Google drive, once shared, anyone can use link to access it, with or without google account. `google.colab.drive` or `google.colab.files` dependencies are not necessary

Comment: the "/export" works. Can you please share where you found information about it?

Comment: you have to make it a public document I beleive.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I found so far.

Pretty similar to what we do on desktop.

Considering you uploaded the file to your Google Drive folder:

- On the left bar click on Files ( below the {x} )
- Select Mount Driver > drive > folder > file (left click and Copy Path)

After that just go to the code and past the path

```
pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/token_rating.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Most Easiest Way I Found**

1. Mount your google drive first

   ```
    import pandas as pd
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
   ```
2. Get the file path and use pd.read_excel()

   df = pd.read_excel('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/data.xlsx')

   df.head()