# Export Excel files from Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I use following codes to save some data frame data, in Google Colab. But it is saved in the "local file system", not in my computer nor Google Drive. How can I get the Excel file from there?
Thanks!

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('hey.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('result.csv')
```

Use Google Chrome. Firefox shows Network Error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to upload the file using something like:

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

Then, you can pick out the file data using something like `uploaded['your_file_here.xls']`.

There's a distinct question that includes recipes for working with Excel files in Drive that might be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47440841/8841057