# PYTHON: How to add a column to Excel Sheet with multiple Sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, addition

I am relatively new to python, and have tried a couple different methods I have seen throughout this website, but nothing seems to work with what I need.

I have an excel file, with two columns of information, and multiple sheets. I would like to add a column to each of these sheets with the header "System". Under the header I need to have all the cells in sheet 1 fill with "System 1" and for sheet 2 "System 2". Each sheet has a different amount of entries, and all are over 1000.

At the end I want to merge all the sheets together making one master file, which I was able to figure out, but I can seem to add a column to the individual sheets. Below is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl
import pprint 

fileName= input("Enter file name here (Case Sensitve) > ")

df = pd.read_excel(fileName +'.xlsx', sheetname=None, ignore_index=True)
xl = pd.ExcelFile(fileName +'.xlsx')

df1 = pd.read_excel(xl, 'System 1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xl, 'System 2')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xl, 'System 3')
df4 = pd.read_excel(xl, 'System 4')
df5 = pd.read_excel(xl, 'System 5')
```

The excel document looks along the lines of this:

```
employee_number email
7000            test1@test.com
11552           test2@test.com
21356           test3@test.com
21365           test4@test.com
22022           test5@test.com
24280           test6@test.com
26279           test7@test.com
```

there are 5 sheets within one document that resemble this.

Comment: First, your code, as written, doesn't run. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice. You need to fix the `load_workbook` line. If you're opening this Excel file, what's in it? Does it have sheets `System 1` and `System 2`? Can you upload a few rows from it, or a sample of it?

Comment: Hello Evan, I apologize, the code I had earlier that ran I erased because the end result wasn't what I needed. I added more information to the original post, in hopes of providing extra clarification.  I think I will try placing each sheet into its own dataframe, and add a column to each dataframe titled "System". Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: I also added  df1['System'] = "System 1" , but is there a more efficient way in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem. In my experience, importing and exporting (particularly exporting) Excel format files can have issues.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('Sample - Superstore.xls')
df['a_new_col'] = np.random.rand()
df.to_excel('New_Excel_File.xlsx')
```

That will import the first worksheet, create a df, and export it to a new Excel file.

If all you want to do is create a new column, the syntax is simply:

```
df['new_col'] = some_data
```

To import all of the sheets of an Excel file, see [Using Pandas to pd.read_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

You may also want to try merging, joining, or concatenating the dataframes, then exporting them. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html