# Referencing different tables/sheets in a database

Tags: python, excel, database, csv

I want to reference a `Questions` table/sheet in my database called `StudentNames`

Where would I implement the reference point so only the `Questions` sheet is accessed

```
def QuestionGenerator():
    questionlist_file = open('StudentNames.csv')
    reader=csv.reader(questionlist_file)
    rownum=0
    array2=[]
    for row in reader:
        array2.append(row)
        rownum=rownum+1
    print(array2)
```

Comment: I have saved a spreadsheet document as a csv file. In excel you can have different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, it looks like csv may not be the best format for what you are trying to do. If you *already* have an excel file with this information, perhaps consider python libraries that have been built for excel, like pandas. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) references arguments (i.e. `sheet_name`) that can be passed to the pandas `read_excel` function to make sure you are only using a specific sheet.

```
    import pandas as pd
    def QuestionGenerator():
       questionlist_file = pd.ExcelFile('StudentNames.csv')
       sheet_of_interest = pd.read_excel(questionlist_file, 'Questions')
       ...
```

Comment: Would i save the excel document as an excel file then? Or keep it as a CSV.

Comment: You'd have to save it as an excel file, yes - although, if it is not *already* an excel file, I'm unsure how you would have had "sheets" in the first place