# Read_Excel Pandas Sheet_Name = None returning only 1 Sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel workbook with 36 sheets (not my fault).  The code below 'works', reads in the file but only the first sheet.  I concat and send to csv and the result is only 'Sheet1".  Thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd

Data = pd.read_excel(open("P://XXDrives//Folder_1//Folder_2//XX.xlsx", "rb"), sheet_name = None)

pd.concat([Data], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

Data.to_csv('C://Users//MyName//Desktop//test.csv')
```

Comment: Reassign the concat.. `Data = pd.concat([Data], axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @pyd Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) (its been asked a couple of times) ;)

Comment: @RR33 Are you trying to append all 35 sheets together?

Comment: Still returns only one sheet of data per the reassign.  Not sure what you mean about the second question.  I tried pd.read_excel(path only) and got the same result.

Comment: @RR33 Just posted my solution to this. Let me know if that helps. If you trying to append all 35 sheets together, I will update the solution accordingly.

Comment: All sheets together vertically.  Each sheet is a different month formatted the same way.

Comment: Upgrade to 0.23.4. There was a bug regarding this parameter.

Comment: @RR33 Just updated my answer. I was in the same shoes as yours few days back :) Let me know if the answer helps.

Comment: Upgrade Completed along with Anoconda up grade.  Ran same script and got this error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

Comment: Yeah you need to remove brackets now that you have a dictionary. It should be `pd.concat(data, axis=0, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @user2285236: good god almighty, that took awhile.  Thanks.  Works great. Now have to add a column in each sheet that takes the sheet 'name' and returns a date  for all rows in the sheets.  So, there may be another post.  Cheers

Answer (score -1):

The code is reading only one sheet because you have specified `sheet_name = None`. If you want it to read specific sheet (lets say a sheet named - 'my_sheet_name'), use `sheet_name = 'my_sheet_name'`

Update: If you want to append all 36 sheets vertically.

```
import pandas as pd
output_df = pd.read_excel(open("P://XXDrives//Folder_1//Folder_2//XX.xlsx", "rb"), sheet_name = 'sheet_1') # Use 1st sheet to populate your output_df
sheets = ['sheet_2', 'sheet_3', 'sheet_4'] #include the names of all the sheets here except the first one.

for i in sheets:
     Data = pd.read_excel(open("P://XXDrives//Folder_1//Folder_2//XX.xlsx", "rb"), sheet_name = i)
     output_df = pd.concat([output_df, Data], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

output_df.to_csv('C://Users//MyName//Desktop//test.csv')
```