# Python pandas excel output not in decided form

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an Excel file with 100 sheets. I need to extract data from each sheets column P beginning from row 7 & create a new file with all extracted data in same column. In my Output file, the data is located in different column, ie(Sheet 2's data in column R, Sheet 3's in column B)

How can I make the data in the same column in the new Output excel?  Thank you.

ps. Combining all sheets' column P data into a single column in single sheet is enough for me

```
import pandas as pd
import os 
Flat_Price = "Flat Pricing.xlsx"
dfs = pd.read_excel(Flat_Price, sheet_name=None, usecols = "P", skiprows=6, indexcol=1, sort=False)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Output.xlsx")
df.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1")
writer.save()
print (os.path.abspath("Output.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Are data confidental?

Comment: You'd have to decide on an organization scheme. It's unlikely that we can be of much help given the information provided.

Comment: I think you can use `pd.ExcelFile()` function. Read each sheet individually into a separate DF and append them later into one single DF in one single column. You can take help from this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I made some changes in my question. The data is not private but I am not so sure if I can post it here. I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @AnonyYam - OK, is possible share input data file via fropbox, gdocs, similar ? Because output of `dfs` should be ordered dictionary, so not sure why is ordering different in output.

Comment: @jezrael File Available here( I deleted Sheet1 , 104&105 becoz they are unrelated) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzchdn18aimqol4/Salesdata%20-%20NOVUM%20WEST.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parameter `header=None` for default 0 column name:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(Flat_Price, 
                    sheet_name=None, 
                    usecols = "P", 
                    skiprows=6, 
                    indexcol=1, 
                    header=None)
```

Then is possible extract number from first level of `MultiIndex`, convert to integer and sorting by [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df =df.set_index([df.index.get_level_values(0).str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False).astype(int), 
                  df.index.get_level_values(1)]).sort_index()
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I am using python for some specific tasks without foundation, thanks for the suggestion and I will try to find out what sort_index does =]

Comment: @AnonyYam - yes, but first was neccesary create iinteger values. Btw, problem here was `concat` sorting, but because there was string `Table` in each sheetname, it was sorted by default lexicographically.