# python: How to read multiple worksheets of the same workbook using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am having excel and want to read the second worksheet. But everytime getting only first worksheet. Is there a way to get second worksheet without giving its name?

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
print dfs
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sheet_name` argument under `pd.read_excel` to read a specific sheet.

Example:

`sheet_name=1` reads second sheet.