# Use particular sheet in pd.read_excel() after uploading data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have uploaded A excel file with multiple sheets using the sheet_name parameter to None. But now I want to access the particular sheet only let's say **'Sheet 1"**. How can I do that on the uploaded data frame?

```
data = pd.read_excel("D:\TUTORIALS\Exercise Files - Data Analysis with Pandas and Python/Data - Multiple Worksheets.xlsx", sheet_name = None)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Comment: when you pass `sheet_name=None` it returns a dictionsry of dataframes per sheet. you can then call each sheet as dict key -> `data['Sheet1']`