# pandas OrderedDict strip space read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, strip, ordereddict

I have an excel file with over 100 sheets. I need to import into pandas and create a dataframe. The problem is some columns headings contain spaces so I get a dataframe with some duplicate columns.

Is it possible to strip a space in columns in OrderedDict? I know I can use `str.strip()` in the dataframe but can't find anything for OrderedDict.

I have the following structure in excel:

```
sheet TEST:
   'ID1' 'ID2'  'ID3'  'ID4'
1   A     2016   val    val 
2   B     2017   val    val
3   C     2018   val    val

sheet TEST2:
   'ID1' 'ID2'  'ID3 ' 'ID4'
1   A     2016   val    val 
2   B     2017   val    val
3   C     2018   val    val

sheet TEST3:
   'ID1' 'ID2'  'ID3' 'ID4 '
1   A     2016   val    val 
2   B     2017   val    val
3   C     2018   val    val
```

At the moment I do the following:

```
df = pd.read_excel (File location, sheet_name = ['TEST', 'TEST2', 'TEST3'])

df = pd.concat(df, axis=0, sort=False)
df = df.reset_index()
```

This is what I get:

```py
   'ID1'  'ID2'  'ID3'  'ID4' 'ID3 ' 'ID4 '
1   A     2016    val    val   NaN    NaN
2   B     2017    val    val   NaN    NaN
3   C     2018    val    val   NaN    NaN
4   A     2016    NaN    val   val    NaN
5   B     2017    NaN    val   val    NaN
6   C     2018    NaN    val   val    NaN
7   A     2016    val    NaN   NaN    val
8   B     2017    val    NaN   NaN    val
9   C     2018    val    NaN   NaN    val
```

This is what I need:

```py
   'ID1'  'ID2'  'ID3'  'ID4' 
1   A     2016    val    val   
2   B     2017    val    val   
3   C     2018    val    val   
4   A     2016    val    val   
5   B     2017    val    val   
6   C     2018    val    val   
7   A     2016    val    val   
8   B     2017    val    val   
9   C     2018    val    val
```

Many thanks

Comment: it is easier if you separate the sheet into different variable, like df1 = sheet1, df2 = sheet2, df3 = sheet3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading in multiple sheets, and your workbook is large, it's [more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521726/1186342) to use `pd.ExcelFile` to create an `ExcelFile` object, then access the sheets individually. It also makes the column name formatting very straight-forward:

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile(filepath)

dfs = []
for sheet in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: great answer, I routinely do the same for very large workbooks with n number of sheets. Didn't know about the performance difference, have you tested this or is there anything you can point me towards for my education?

Comment: Yep, just added a link to a question discussing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26521266/1186342

Answer (score 0):

Simply define separate, to make it easier:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel (File location TEST, sheet_name = 'TEST')
df2 = pd.read_excel (File location TEST2, sheet_name = 'TEST2')
df3 = pd.read_excel (File location TEST3, sheet_name = 'TEST3')
```

and then just concat it like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=0)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: If you wanted to apply it with loop, just do the following:
assuming that you have 150 sheets, and the name of your sheet is iterable like "TEST" "TEST2" "TEST3".."TEST150"

```
listdf = []
name=""
for x in range(150):
    if x==0: name = "TEST"
    elif x>0: name= "TEST" + str(x+1)
    df = pd.read_excel (File location TEST, sheet_name = name)
    listdf.append(df)

newbigdf = pd.concat(listdf, axis=0)
```