# How can i read multiple excel sheets (Case insensitive) using read_excel function in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using below code to read excel sheets from an excel file

```
df=pd.read_excel(ExcelFile,sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

What if i have 10 excel files with multiple tabs for example

`Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3` and in some files

sheet names are in Capital for example "SHEET1", in this case how can i read those sheet names.

Comment: do you need to read all sheets in each  excel file?

Comment: Maybe this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26521726/12128167)

Answer (score 1):

you need `sheet_name=None`

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',sheet_name=None)
```

This will return a dictionary where key will be sheet_names and value will be dataframes.

you can see all the sheet names by,

```
dfs.keys()
```

to retrieve specific sheet data,

```
df = dfs['sheet_name']
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the pandas read_excel documentation you can give the sheet names as a list.
so you can give the sheet names like this:

```
sheet_names = ['sheet1','sheet2','sheet3']
df=pd.read_excel(ExcelFile,sheet_name=sheet_names)
```

if you give `sheet_name = None` It will read all the sheets.