# pandas with excel sheet into an excel file

Tags: python, pandas

[image: <code>** excel sheet into an excel file **</code>]**Could you help me, I one Excel file with multiple excel sheets. try to create each excel sheet into an excel file. I did try multiple ways but it didn't work  **

Comment: For each of the sheet, apply ```read_excel```, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook

Comment: `dfs = {sheet : pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=sheet) for sheet in file.sheet_names}` will create a dictionary of pandas dataframes with the sheet as the dictionary key.