# Sheet selection with panda read function

Tags: excel, pandas

I am sorry but I am new to this. Is it possible to choose only some excel sheets in the excel fil for pd.read_excel function? Thank you

Comment: Yes. Did you check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)