# How to merge columns from multiple sheets in one excel file by pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

How to combine the columns from every sheet, using pandas?

I need to iterate through each sheet in one Excel file, and merge every sheet separately, like the following images.

I have around 1000 sheets in one file, and sheets names are not same.

How to do the iteration and merging?

[image: show sheet1]

[image: show sheet2]

[image: show sheet3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelFile('Downloads\wbook.xlsx')

writer.sheet_names
#prints names of the spreadsheets.

excelfile = pd.ExcelWriter('workb1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
for i in writer.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(writer, sheet_name=i, header=None)
    df[3] = df.iloc[:, 0] + ' ' + df.iloc[:, 1]
    df.to_excel(excelfile, sheet_name=i, index=False)
excelfile.save()
```

Creates a new spreadsheet with the combined columns A and B for each sheet in the original workbook.

Answer (score 1):

- It seems easiest to use [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `sheet_name=None`.

  - Specify `None` to get all sheets.
  - This will create a `dict` of dataframes with the `sheet_names` as the keys.
  - Iterate through the `keys` and `values`, to combine the two columns and write back to a file.
- As per your comment, the [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method may be used on either column, as shown in the following code.

### Write just the new combined column back to the sheet

```py
import pandas as pd

# create dict of dataframes
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

# iterate through dict
for k, v in df.items():
    with pd.ExcelWriter('combined.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl') as writer:  # write sheets to a new file
        combined = v.iloc[:, 0].fillna('xxx') + ' ' + v.iloc[:, 1].fillna('xxx')  # combine the first and second column
        combined.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k, index=False, header=False)
```

### Write the original, and the combined columns back to the sheet

```py
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for k, v in df.items():
    with pd.ExcelWriter('combined.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl') as writer:  # write sheets to a new file
        v['comb'] = v.iloc[:, 0].fillna('xxx') + ' ' + v.iloc[:, 1].fillna('xxx')  # combine the first and second column
        v.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k, index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in many posts([Using Pandas to pd.read_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook))

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Sheet2')
```

To merge dataframes by columns,

```
df1.append(df2)
df1.append(df3)
...
```

The above code will result a merged dataframe saved in df1.

Answer (score 0):

## try to read the 3 excel sheets separately as shown below and then use pd.merge to        merge df1, df2, df3 as a single data frame by index or any other columns to match the right columns of all the three data frame

```
            import pandas as pd
            df1 = pd.read_excel(f_name.xls, 'Sheet1')
            df2 = pd.read_excel(f_name.xls, 'Sheet2')
            df3 = pd.read_excel(f_name.xls, 'Sheet3')
            df = pd.merge(df1, (pd.merge(df2, df3, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: @hhp, welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for an answer. However, please don't use the header (#) symbols just to make the text stand out more, it won't help.