# Read excel sheet in pandas with different sheet names in a pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple excel files in a loop using read_excel :

Different excel files contain sheet names which contain the word "staff"
eg Staff_2013 , Staff_list etc

Is there a way to read all these files dynamically using some wild card concept ?

Something like the code below :

```
df = pd.read_excel(folder,col_names=True,sheet_name='Staff*')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the sheets and select the ones you want to read one by one.

For instance:

```
xls_file = pd.ExcelFile('my_excel_file.xls')
staff_fnames = [sheet for sheet in xls.sheet_names if sheet.startswith('Staff')]
for staff_fname in staff_fnames:
    df = pd.read_excel('my_excel_file.xls'), sheet_name=staff_fname)
```

Or, if you don't mind loading all the sheets, you can also use `sheet_name=None` to load all sheets in a `dict` and filter afterwards:

```
dfs_dict = pd.read_excel('my_excel_file.xls', sheet_name=None)
dfs_dict = {s: df for s, df in dfs_dict.items() if s.startswith('Staff')}
```

Comment: Perfect, i know this is could be problematic. however it does solve the issue for now

Comment: `read_excel` can read multiple sheets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081870. Your explanation, and claim that you have to read the sheets one-by-one, is incorrect.