# missing columns by read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to read an Excel file with multiple sheets, all sheets have the same structure, all have 152 columns, but pandas doesn't read the full structure of a sheet, read only 97 columns of 152, any ideas?

I use this simple code

```py
    def read_excel(self, header=0):
        self._excel = pd.read_excel(io=self.path_read,
                                    sheet_name=self.sheets,
                                    header=header
                                    )
```

Comment: How do you specify the name of the 'sheet' you want to read?

Comment: In a list

self.sheets = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', ...]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Comment: Nou, my problem is different :/

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: Yep, but the problem is with pandas function :c

Comment: Are you sure it does not read the whole excel? Does any error come out? Have you tried `df.shape` to see the exact number of rows & columns?

Comment: And another question. Do you store each sheet to a different dataframe? And please, provide the `header` variable in your post.

Comment: Thanks for all, I've solved this, the problem was Windows Security config

Comment: Nice. Now that you solve it, you can post your solution as the answer, so others can be helped, if they stuck at the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this horrible problem; the problem was Windows Security config that makes impossible to read the full Excel. A simple solution is to run the code as administrator.