# Concat Read Excel Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm needing to read in an excel file and read all sheets inside that excel file.

I've tried:

```
sample_df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("sample_master.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)
```

This code worked, but it's suddenly giving me this error:

```
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"
```

After reading in the excel file, I need to run the following command:

```
new_id = sample_df.loc[(sample_df['Sequencing_ID'] == line) & (sample_df['Experiment_ID'] == experiment_id), \
                               'Sample_ID_for_report'].item()
```

Any help?

Comment: Maybe the excel workbook you are reading now that gives this error has only one sheet, therefore the return from pd.read_excel is a single DataFrame and not dictionary of DataFrames.

Comment: The return is either a DataFrame or dict of DataFrames so if you want something more flexible do the `read_excel` then check the type and if it's a dict concat, else you're all set.

Comment: There are still multiple sheets in the excel file.

Comment: Let's make sure.  `type(pd.read_excel("sample_master.xlsx", sheet_name=None))`  What is the output of that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Comment: pd.read_excel("sample_master.xlsx", sheet_name=None) This will return the concatenated Dataframe you don't need to use pd.concat() I guess. @Kyle

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to know all of the sheets that need to be read in. Second, you will want to iterate over each sheet.

1. *Getting Sheet names*.- You can get a list of the sheet names in a workbook with `sheets = pd.ExcelFile(path).sheet_names`, where `path` is the full path to your file. The function below reads a workbook and returns a list of sheet names that contain specific key words.

```py
      import re
      import pandas as pd

      def get_sheets(path):
     
        sheets = pd.ExcelFile(path).sheet_names
        sheets_to_process = []
        for sheet in sheets:
          excludes = ['exclude_term1', 'exclude_term1']
          includes = ['find_term1', 'find_term2']
          sheet_stnd = re.sub('[^0-9A-Za-z_]+', '', sheet).lower().strip(' ') 
          for exclude in excludes:
            if sheet_stnd != exclude:
                for include in includes:
                    if include in sheet_stnd:
                        sheets_to_process.append(sheet)
         return list(set(sheets_to_process))
```

2. *Loop over sheets*- You can then loop over the sheets to read them in. In this example,

```py
for sheet in get_sheets(path):
  df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("sample_master.xlsx", sheet_name=sheet), 
                      ignore_index=True)
```

Depending on your use case, you may also want to append each sheet into a larger data frame