# How to run pandas on multiple spreadsheets except one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spreadsheet

How to run pandas for multiple sheet but with exception of one? I have multiple documents with random sheet number and I need to run them all but with exception of one with description so I need to skip that one.

```
sheets = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The sheet you want to exclude is named `description`?

Comment: Yes, the sheet I want to exclude is named 'description'.

Comment: Answered by [Vikash Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081870/202229). First, read in all the sheets, get a list `sheetnames` of their names, then drop the unwanted one with (say)`sheetnames.remove('description')`, then reread them with `sheet_name=sheetnames`

Comment: @Corralien: you mean `names=`. Ok but that would no longer be the OP's question. `read_excel()` has 27 parameters so yes there are lots of ways to break it when reading multiple sheets. But if you have a separate question from the OP, post your own question (or post an answer to [Using Pandas to pd.read_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the doc says, [`pd.read_excel(..., sheet_name=...)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) parameter allows you to specify a list of names, or list of indices. So just list all the sheets you want to import.

UPDATE: the parameter is `sheet_name`, there's no parameter `exclude_sheet_name`, so yes if you don't know the list of names/indices of the sheets you do want to read, you'll have to `pd.read_excel()` twice, and yes that can be time-consuming for huge sheets. If you don't like that, [file an enhance request on pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+read_excel). Also, 'sheet_name'(/'exclude_sheet_name) can currently only be names or indices, not a regex. Either/both of those would be legit enhance requests.

> ***sheet_name*** str, int, list, or `None`, default `0`
>
> Strings are used for sheet names. Integers are used in zero-indexed sheet positions. Lists of strings/integers are used to request multiple sheets. Specify `None` to get all sheets.