# I want to read Multiple sheets in excel into multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

An excel file has multiple sheets, i want to read those sheets into multiple pandas dataframe. Is there a way to do it? Please Let Me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls') 
sheets_names = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
dfs = []
for sheet_name in sheets_names: 
    df[i] = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
```

Comment: Add some detail for you answer, just code is not enought to understand.