# How to use Azure databricks to read and write excel data with multiple sheets from ADLS gen 2

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to implement the below logic in Azure databricks using pyspark.
I have a below file which has multiple sheets in it. the file is present on adls gen 2.
I want to read the data of all sheets into a different file and write the file to some location in adls gen 2 itself.

Note: All sheet has same schema ( Id, Name)

My final output file should have data from all the sheets. Also I need to create an additional column which stores the sheetName info

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic

- Using Pandas to  read multiple worksheets of the same workbook [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)
- concat the multiple dataframes in Pandas and make it single data frame [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html)
- Convert the Panda dataframe into pyspark dataframe .[link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/convert-pandas-to-pyspark-dataframe/)
- Apply Business logic which you want to implement.