# Read .xlsx file from s3 bucket and convert each tab to csv with tab name and upload to bucket

Tags: python, excel, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlrd 
import openpyxl 
from io import StringIO  
import boto3 

def lambda_handler(event,context):  
    df=pd.read_excel('s3://my-bucket/XL/test-xls.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')    
    bucket = 'my-bucket'   
    csv_buffer = StringIO() 
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer) 
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3') 

    # write the data back as a CSV 
    s3_resource.Object(bucket,'XL/test-csv.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

1. Above code  is  working fine for one excel but  I  am searching for  solution where I can read XLSX file
2. If XLSX file has  3 tab then those 3 tabs should get converted into 3 different CSV and save file into bucket with tabname.csv

Comment: For reading multiple sheets from the same workbook (2), see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook) helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) instead of pandas. xlsx2csv with `-n` option might work.

Also xlsx2csv have more options for sheet tabs, you can choose what suits you.

Answer (score 0):

To read a particular sheet you just need to pass it as a parameter to the read_excel function:

```py
excel_object = s3.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)['Body'].read()
df_sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_object, sheet_name='name_of_sheet1')
df_sheet2 = pd.read_excel(excel_object, sheet_name='name_of_sheet2')
```

*Note: You can also use the 0-based index of the sheet*

If you want to extract every sheet, you can get the sheet names using the `.sheet_names` property

```py
excel = pd.ExcelFile(s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=source_key)['Body'].read())
names = excel.sheet_names
for name in names:
  sheet = pd.read_excel(excel, sheet_name=name)
```

and extract every sheet in a loop.

[pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)