# Read all Excel sheets except one of them

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm using this line code to get all sheets from an Excel file:

`excel_file = pd.read_excel('path_file',skiprows=35,sheet_name=None)`

- `sheet_name=None` option gets all the sheets.

How do I get all sheets except one of them?

Comment: I think you can pass sheet names as a list of strings to `sheet_name`. Please see [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You can also mix and match sheet number and names/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Pandas to pd.read\_excel() for multiple worksheets of the same workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521266/using-pandas-to-pd-read-excel-for-multiple-worksheets-of-the-same-workbook)

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is exclude one of the sheets, there is not much to change from your base code.

Assume `file.xlsx` is an excel file with multiple sheets, and you want to skip `'Sheet1'`.

One possible solution is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Returns a dictionary with key:value := sheet_name:df
xlwb = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
unwanted_sheet = 'Sheet1'

# list comprehension that filters out unwanted sheet
# all other sheets are kept in df_generator
df_generator = (items for keys, items in xlwb.items() 
                if keys != unwanted_sheet)

# get to the actual dataframes
for df in df_generator:
    print(df.head())
```